# Qml virtual keyboard key press

Tags: qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

I was able to show the virtual keyboard using the below code.

```
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.0
Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello KeyBoard")

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        z: 89
        y: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right



    }
}
```

How can I get the pressed 'keys' from the InputPanel.I dont need to display the keys in TextField.